# Find work done by a force field using Green's theorem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have to find the work done by a vector field, and while I understand Green's Theorem, I can't set up the limits of integration. The particle moves around the ellipse $x^2+4y^2=4$. How would I set up a double integral with this? I tried to in polar coordinates, and while I know the limits of $\theta$, I can't think of what the limits on R would be for an ellipse. Was converting to polar coordinates a mistake?

Comment: The work done is a simple line integral $\int_{\Gamma} \overline{f} \cdot d\overline{s}$ You have not specified the force vector field in your problem, so you'll have to specify that in addition to the trajectory.

Comment: yes, but I have to use greens theorem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The work done is 
$$
\oint{\bar{f} \cdot d\bar{s}} = \oint{ (f_x,f_y) \cdot (dx, dy)} =\\
\oint{f_x dx + f_y dy} 
$$
As per Green's theorem, this is 
$$
\oint{f_x dx + f_y dy} = \iint \limits_{D}   \left ( \frac{\partial f_y}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial f_x}{\partial y} \right ) dx dy 
$$
Once you specify your force vector field $\bar{f}$, you can find its components $f_x$ and $f_y$ and evaluate the double integral on the right.

Edited to add: As for the transformation to polar, you can certainly do it.
The limits of the double integral for the ellipse are $\theta=(0,2\pi)$ for the outer integral and $r=(0,\sqrt{a^2 \cos^2 \theta + b^2 \sin^2 \theta}$) for the inner integral, where $a=2$ and $b=1$ for your ellipse.

Comment: It is worth noting, since the notation may be confusing, that in this case, $f_x$ refers to the $x$ component of $f$, rather than the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have calculate everything to set up a double integral for the work using Greens Thm,

$$\oint_C \langle p,q \rangle \cdot d\vec r = \iint \limits_{D}  (q_x-p_y) dA $$

Note that the equation for the ellipse can be expressed as,

$$(\frac{x}{2})^2+(\frac{y}{1})^2=1$$

Just use the "modified polar" transformation,

$$x=2r \cos (\theta)$$
$$y=1 r \sin (\theta)$$

With $r \in [0,1]$ and $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$. Compute Jacobian, substitute and precede.

Answer (score 0):

To set up the double integral over the ellipse, it might be best to do the change of variables $u=x$ and $v=2y$.  The Jacobian for this transformation is $2$, so you end up integrating over a circle of radius $2$ in the $u,v$ plane.  And that's easy in polar.